# Self Referencing / CTE / Finding a trail for one mapped Entity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Aaaack.

I'm having a brain freeze moment.

Below I have a self referencing table.
And I have a CTE to self-join and get the info.

What I'm trying to get is the "complete hierarchy path" for ONE person.

Note that I do NOT have a predetermined number of levels.  (My example below is made up, please take the person to location relationship with a grain of salt, it ~represents my data structure, it is not my real data structure)

Note that @PersonUUID_Me is mapped to the "Town" level, while @PersonUUID_Nobody is mapped to the street level.  Aka, the 2 different people have 2 different row-counts for their hierarchy.  So I cannot bank on "Depth" being 3 (or anything pre-determined).

What I get now is only the "bottom" row for the Person_Me.

```
AAAAAAAA-6666-6666-6666-666666666666    Strasburg   AAAAAAAA-7777-7777-7777-777777777777    3
```

What I'd like to get:

```
99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999    USA (NULL)  0
AAAAAAAA-8888-8888-8888-888888888888    Virginia    99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999    1
AAAAAAAA-7777-7777-7777-777777777777    Shenandoah  AAAAAAAA-8888-8888-8888-888888888888    2
AAAAAAAA-6666-6666-6666-666666666666    Strasburg   AAAAAAAA-7777-7777-7777-777777777777    3
```

and (not shown), if I ran it for the Person_Nobody, I would get:

```
99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999    USA (NULL)  0
BBBBBBBB-8888-8888-8888-888888888888    North Carolina  99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999    1
BBBBBBBB-7777-7777-7777-777777777777    Wake    BBBBBBBB-8888-8888-8888-888888888888    2
BBBBBBBB-6666-6666-6666-666666666666    Raleigh BBBBBBBB-7777-7777-7777-777777777777    3
BBBBBBBB-5555-5555-5555-555555555555    Main St BBBBBBBB-6666-6666-6666-666666666666    4
```

Gaaaa.  I'm missing something basic, I know, but I'm brain-freezing.

Again, I'm trying to get the complete hierarchy trail for one person, the person is mapped to the "bottom-most" hierarchy-element.....but the "depth" of that element is not pre-determined.  In this example, it would be "I'll map the hierarchy value that I know the most about, but I may not know the most detailed piece of information (street), I may only know your state or town..

```
-- START TSQL

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Person]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Person] 
END 



IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[BreadCrumbTrail]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[BreadCrumbTrail] 
END 
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BreadCrumbTrail] ( 
      [BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    , [BreadCrumbTrailName] varchar(64) NOT NULL
    , [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    , ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID [uniqueidentifier] NULL

)


GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.BreadCrumbTrail ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BreadCrumbTrail PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BreadCrumbTrail] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BreadCrumbTrail_SelfRef FOREIGN KEY ([ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID]) REFERENCES dbo.[BreadCrumbTrail] (BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID) 
GO


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Person]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Person] 
END 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person] ( 

    [PersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID]  [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (PersonUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].Person ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Person_To_BreadCrumb FOREIGN KEY ([BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID]) REFERENCES dbo.[BreadCrumbTrail] (BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID) 
GO




declare @PersonUUID_Me [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_Me = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'

declare @PersonUUID_Nobody [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_Nobody = '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222'

declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Country [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Country = '99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999'
declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State1 [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State1 = 'AAAAAAAA-8888-8888-8888-888888888888'
declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County1 [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County1 = 'AAAAAAAA-7777-7777-7777-777777777777'
declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town1 [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town1 = 'AAAAAAAA-6666-6666-6666-666666666666'

declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State2 [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State2 = 'BBBBBBBB-8888-8888-8888-888888888888'
declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County2 [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County2 = 'BBBBBBBB-7777-7777-7777-777777777777'
declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town2 [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town2 = 'BBBBBBBB-6666-6666-6666-666666666666'

declare @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Street2 [uniqueidentifier]
select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Street2 = 'BBBBBBBB-5555-5555-5555-555555555555'



INSERT INTO [dbo].[BreadCrumbTrail] ( 
      [BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID] 
    , [BreadCrumbTrailName]
    , [CreateDate] 
    , ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID
     )
Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Country , 'USA' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , NULL
UNION ALL Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State1 , 'Virginia' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Country
UNION ALL Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County1 , 'Shenandoah' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State1
UNION ALL Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town1, 'Strasburg' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County1
UNION ALL Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State2 , 'North Carolina' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Country
UNION ALL Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County2 , 'Wake' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_State2
UNION ALL Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town2, 'Raleigh' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_County2
UNION ALL Select @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Street2, 'Main St' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town2


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] (    [PersonUUID] , [BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , [CreateDate] )
            Select @PersonUUID_Me , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Town1 ,  'Coder', 'Granada' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL   Select @PersonUUID_Nobody , @BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID_Street2 ,  'Body', 'No' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP




/*
Select  [PersonUUID] , [BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , [CreateDate] 
from [dbo].[Person] per
    where per.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me
*/




 ;WITH cteLocation (BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, [BreadCrumbTrailName] , ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , Depth)
 AS
 (
    Select bc1.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, bc1.[BreadCrumbTrailName], bc1.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , 0 as Depth From dbo.BreadCrumbTrail bc1 where bc1.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID IS NULL
    Union ALL
    Select bc2.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, bc2.[BreadCrumbTrailName] , bc2.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , Depth + 1 
    From dbo.BreadCrumbTrail bc2 
    inner join cteLocation cteL on bc2.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID = cteL.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID
 )

 Select cteLoc.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, [BreadCrumbTrailName] , ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , Depth 
 from cteLocation cteLoc
 join [dbo].[Person] per on per.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID = cteLoc.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID
    where per.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me
```

Comment: I guess it wasn't so super-simple after all.

Comment: I found a similar posting here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1075989-203-6.aspx      I'll update here (and give proper credit) if it is answered at that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another CTE to backtrack from person up the hierarchy:

```
 ;WITH cteLocation (BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, [BreadCrumbTrailName] , ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , Depth)
 AS
 (
    Select bc1.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, bc1.[BreadCrumbTrailName], bc1.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , 0 as Depth From dbo.BreadCrumbTrail bc1 where bc1.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID IS NULL
    Union ALL
    Select bc2.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, bc2.[BreadCrumbTrailName] , bc2.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , Depth + 1 
    From dbo.BreadCrumbTrail bc2 
    inner join cteLocation cteL on bc2.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID = cteL.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID
 )
,ctePerson as
(
    Select cteLoc.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, [BreadCrumbTrailName] , ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID , Depth 
    from cteLocation cteLoc
    join [dbo].[Person] per on per.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID = cteLoc.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID
    where per.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Nobody

    union all

    Select c.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, c.[BreadCrumbTrailName], c.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID, c.Depth 
    from cteLocation c
    inner join ctePerson p on c.BreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID = p.ParentBreadCrumbTrailSurrogateUUID
)
select *
from ctePerson
order by Depth
```